# How to provide 777 default permission on all files within a given Linux folder

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ami

I have a need to make any files that are created in the specific Linux directory to have 777 permission.

I would like to have all the users to be able to do Read, Write and Execute on all files under this folder. So what is the best way or Linux command to make it happen?

What I am doing is that I am spinning off two separate containers one for Nginx server and one for PHP:FPM app server to host Laravel 5.4 app.

Please consider the following scenario. I have a docker application container A (PHP:FPM) which is used to serve the web application files to docker container B (Nginx). Now when I access the website, I am delivering the web pages through the web container. Both the containers are within the same network and I share the volumes from my app container to my web container. But when the web container tries to read the files on the app container I get the error which is something like below:

> The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be
>   opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

So I added `RUN chmod -R 777 storage` in my docker file.
However it is not solving the issue.

So I also tried using SGID to fix the issue by adding one more line in my dockerfile as `RUN chmod -R ug+rwxs storage`. Still it is not solving the issue of permission.

On a separate note, funny thing is that on my MAC Docker container this works without any issue ( I mean without adding chmod -R 777 to folder or using SGID for setting permission to a folder in my docker file). But when the same code is run on Linux AMI EC2 instance (Amazon AMI Linux EC2) ... the permission issue start to occur.

**So how do I fix this ?**

Comment: You could use [`setfacl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/setfacl.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to launch both containers using the same user identified by the same uid. For instance you can choose root or any uid when running the container:

```
docker run --user root ...
```

Alternatively, you can switch to another user, before startup, inside your Dockerfile by adding the following before the CMD or ENTRYPOINT

```
USER root
```

Comment: yamenk : OK. But how do I add this in the docker file ? I have two separate docker files - one for app and another for web. How do I add this instruction in dockerfile?

Comment: I added this in the my app.docker file and web.dockerfile after the FROM statement. But it does not solve the issue :( !

Comment: @Andy If you exec into the container, `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` what user is showing?

Comment: I am using docker compose. So I do docker-compose exec <container-name> bash -C.  And it logs me in as a root user in both app and web container.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by figuring out user name under which cache files are created when someone access the application url . And then updating my dockerfile to include statement for SGID ownership for that user on the root of app folder where all source code resides (so all subfolder and files included later in whatever way ... at run-time sometime... are accessible from web container for that user) and then using chmod 777 permission on specific folders that needs to have chmod 777 permission.